# ASP.NET Core 404 when serving pdb and clr files with app.UseStaticFiles()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, uno-platform

I have a basic ASP.NET Core app that serves a Uno Platform Wasm app via app.UseStaticFiles(). Whenever .pdb or .clr files are requested, a 404 is returned. This can easily be reproduced by creating an AspNet Core app serving a clr file.

I tested this by making an ASP.Net Core app serving a txt and clr file via app.UseStaticFiles(). The txt file returns 200, however the clr file returns 404.

I tried including the following in my web.config, to no avail

```xml
<system.webServer>
  <security>
     <requestFiltering>
        <fileExtensions>
           <add fileExtension=".clr" allowed="true" />
           <add fileExtension=".pdb" allowed="true" />
        </fileExtensions>
     </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Is there another mechanism to allow clr and pdb files to be served?

Comment: See [Non-standard content types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.1#non-standard-content-types) and [FileExtensionContentTypeProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.1#fileextensioncontenttypeprovider).

Comment: Thank you! Missed that detail...

Comment: Here's a great post about how to publish an Uno WASM Project: https://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post-2019-03-20-publishing-uno-webassembly-wasm-to-azure-app-service-aspx/